# RestSharp v107+ unable to add parameter with both content type and parameter name

Tags: restsharp

I'm using an API that requires two multipart formdata parameters in a POST to upload a file. One called "data" with a JSON input and one called "binary" with a file. I can't find a way of adding the JSON object with the parameter name (the file part is fine)

Here is my code;

```
var request = new RestRequest(url,Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Host", _connectionDetails._HostUrl);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\test.xlsx");
        request.AddFile("binary", bytes, "test.xlsx", "multipart/form-data");
        request.AddJsonBody(fileDetailsDataObject);
        //request.AddParameter("data", fileDetailsDataObject, ParameterType.RequestBody));
        //request.AddBody(fileDetailsDataObject);
```

This is the Swagger URL for the API I am trying to use if that helps (I'm trying to use the Students - Student Document ** Beta ** method)

[Swagger documentation](https://developerdemo.isams.cloud/Main/swagger/ui/index#!/Students_-_Student_Document__**_Beta_**/StudentDocument_PostAsyncBySchoolid)

I've tried .AddJsonBody, .AddParameter, AddBody

**AddJsonBody**
request.AddJsonBody(fileDetailsDataObject);

Adds with Content-type application/json but it also sets the name to application/json with no way to override;

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/json"

**AddParameter**
request.AddParameter("data", fileDetailsDataObject, ParameterType.RequestBody));

Adds with parameter name correctly but content type is set to text/plain so the JSON isn't working

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=data

**AddBody **
request.AddBody(fileDetailsDataObject, "application/json");

Adds with Content-type application/json but it also sets the name to application/json with no way to override;

I need a way to override both the content type and the parameter name, happy to use another client library if another works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
request.AddParameter(new JsonParameter("data", <jsonObjectOrString>))
```

In addition to your already existing request.AddFile of course.